# Strategy to deploy Headless CMS (Strapi) and Vue-based NodeJS web application on cPanel

Tags: vue.js, deployment, cpanel, strapi

Hello – thank you for providing helpful answers time and time again.

I have built a simple portfolio website for a client using Vue (NodeJS) for the front-end, and Strapi for the CMS/database. The current project folder structure is as follows:

```
|-- backend (Strapi)
|   |-- api
|   |-- build
|   |-- config
|   |-- extensions
|   |-- node_modules
|   |-- public
|   |-- README.md
|   |-- favicon.ico
|   |-- package.json
|   `-- yarn.lock
`-- frontend (Vue)
    |-- node_modules
    |-- public
    |-- src
    |-- README.md
    |-- babel.config.cjs
    |-- package-lock.json
    |-- package.json
    `-- yarn.lock
```

I am using a cPanel-based shared hosting at the moment, and the whole configuration is at the edge of my understanding right now. I wonder what the easiest deployment method within these parameters would be... Of course, new solutions are equally welcome.

Comment: Have you found solution? It is to install Strapi on shared server, but I am facing issues with it. 'Sharp' is the module which gives errors.